# How do I find out how many files are in a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I need to get a count of the number of files in a directory.  I could get the names of all the files in the directory using `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` and take the length of that array but that takes too long on large directories.  Is there a way to get just the count without having to get the names?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe so, no - at least not in vanilla .NET. I suspect it's not the actual fetching of the names that takes the time - it's the OS walking through the directory internals. There *may* be a Win32 call you could make via P/Invoke.

How large is the directory you're looking at? In general it's at least *traditionally* not been a good idea to have more than a few hundred files in a directory. File systems have improved at this in general, but I don't know what the current state is with NTFS and Fat32.

Comment: Indeed, the filesystem itself does not keep the count. It must count the entire list to find the count - which is why it takes the same amount of time.

Comment: what do you mean by vanilla .NET ?

Comment: @Pacerier: I mean without making P/Invoke calls to a Win32 function.

Answer (score 7):

I did a little test - wrote the same task in C++/Qt and C++/CLI:

```
LARGE_INTEGER i1, i2;       

QueryPerformanceCounter(&i1);       

int count = IO::Directory::GetFiles(L"c:\\windows\\system32")->Length;

QueryPerformanceCounter(&i2);

__int64 result = i2.QuadPart - i1.QuadPart;
```

Result is about 16.500.000

and

```
LARGE_INTEGER i1, i2;

QueryPerformanceCounter(&i1);

intcount = QDir("c:/windows/system32").entryList(QDir::Files).count();

QueryPerformanceCounter(&i2);

__int64 result += i2.QuadPart - i1.QuadPart;
```

Result is about 2.100.000.000

Files count is 2125

Answer (score 3):

There is no faster way. No matter what you use, it all boils down to `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` Win32 calls.
You could try using something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FileSystemEnumerator.aspx), but it will probably take just as much time -- but maybe with a little less memory usage (= probably not worth it).

Answer (score 1):

So far, in most languages I came across, you get this information only by walking the folder and counting the files. I doubt there is a Windows API call to get only the count (but I can be surprised!).
Advantage of the method: flexibility - you can filter out some file types, walk down recursively or ignore folders, etc.

If the method is slow for you, maybe you should get a better method, like not creating an array filled with directory info (takes time to fill it! not to mention memory cost and garbage collection time) but using an iterator: a bit more work (but once you get the function, it is always there) but much more efficient.