# Determine number of files in a directory

Tags: c#, .net

I need to determine the number of files/subdirectories in a directory. I don't care which files/directories are actually in that directory. Is there a more efficient way than using

```
_directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Length +
_directoryInfo.GetFiles().Length
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192951/quicker-quickest-way-to-get-number-of-files-in-a-directory-with-over-200-000-f

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349251/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-files-are-in-a-directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's probably about as good as it gets, but you should use [`GetFileSystemInfos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/806sc8c5.aspx) instead which will give you both files and directories:

```
_directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().Length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

then just take the size of the filePaths array

code from:
[C#-Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `GetFileSystemEntries` method found in the `Directory` class and then query the `Length` of the array of items returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyDirectory\");
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.*");

int NumberOfFilesInDir;

foreach( FileInfo file in files )
{
   NumberOfFilesInDir++;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do files.Length?

Comment: I'm a self taught programmer and have not used that way before. I wasn't trying to imply that the original answer wasn't good, I was simply offering another way... :-)