# Reading an e pub file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, epub

I have files in e pub format. I have to show their contents to the user. How do I read them in asp.net? Can it be done through javascript?

Comment: whatever may be the format you can use stream reader for that if you can see the contents in notepad

Comment: @PratikGupta Epub is actually Zip file format.

Comment: any comments on my answer before the bounty runs out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authoritative?  What could be better then a StackOverflow answer?  I started from this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870594/is-there-a-c-sharp-epub-library ) and gleaned a few usefull links:

- Usefull information on displaying text in a web browser using javascript so it paginates nicely: [HTML book-like pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination/3636957#3636957)
- A C# open source library for reading ePub files, the sample code on the home page includes how to get the contents as HTML: http://epubreader.codeplex.com/
- There are other libraries which may come in handy if the ePub reader library on codeplex doesn't pan out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/epubsharp/, and http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

You can't do this with just JavaScript of course, you'll have a server side like a web service or code behind on your asp.net webpage which opens the epub file, extracts the contents as HTML and returns it to the client, but I think there is enough here to get you started.

Comment: @explorer - I just tried it, from the copy of the link you provided, and it opened fine.

Comment: Please which of the links. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just to add then i suggest the steps:

Step 1: unzip the file using C#,.net code having some third party library.

Refer : [recommend a library/API to unzip file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023476/recommend-a-library-api-to-unzip-file-in-c-sharp)

Step 2: Check whether in the extracted folder there is only one file or more.

Refer: [How do I find out how many files are in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349251/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-files-are-in-a-directory)

Step 3 :Read the file using stream reader in c#.net

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328963(v=vs.71).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Answer (score 2):

Epub file is actually a zip archive that contains

- xml files for meta data, table of contents etc
- xhtml or dtbook (xml) + gif, jpeg, png, svg + css for content

To be able to display epub you will have to be able to handle all of the above. Here [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format/2034410#2034410) you'll find what you have to do to open epub step by step - it's an example for iphone, but it should be enough.